# Transition em Javascript com css

Tags: javascript, html, css, transição

Olá, Boa Noite!

Estou desenvolvendo um web site, e vendo um vídeo aula consegui criar um slide em JavaScript, só que preciso que ele passe com um transition mais lento pois está bem rápido a passada entre os slides. Pesquisei e infelizmente não consegui fazer, alguém consegue me ajudar?

```
            <div class="slide">
            <a href=""><img id="banner"></a>
        </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var intervalo = 5000;

        function slide1() {
            document.getElementById("banner").src="img/slide1.png";
            setTimeout("slide2()", intervalo);
        }

        function slide2() {
            document.getElementById("banner").src="img/slide2.png";
            setTimeout("slide3()",  intervalo);
        }

        function slide3() {
            document.getElementById("banner").src="img/slide3.png";
            setTimeout("slide4()", intervalo);
        }               

        function slide4() {
            document.getElementById("banner").src="img/slide4.png";
            setTimeout("slide1()", intervalo);
        }   
    </script>
```

Obrigado!

Comment: Acha 5 segundos rápido demais?

Answer (score 1):

Como está fazendo de uma forma mais de iniciante, vou mostrar uma forma sem mexer muito no seu código, que poderia ser melhor.

Crie uma outra função onde será feita a transição. No CSS coloque a propriedade `transition` abaixo no banner:

```
#banner{
   transition: opacity 500ms;
}
```

O valor `500ms` que dizer *meio segundo* (500 milissegundos). Esse tempo deve ser exatamente o mesmo com o do `setTimeout` que colocarei na função criada. Se quiser que a transição seja mais lenta ou mais rápida, basta alterar os dois valores (no CSS e no JS). Veja:

```js
var intervalo = 2000;
var slide = 1; // variável para controlar qual função a chamar
function transicao(){

   document.getElementById("banner").style.opacity = "0";
   
   setTimeout(function(){
      document.getElementById("banner").style.opacity = "1";
      switch(slide){
         case 1:
            slide2(); break;
         case 2:
            slide3(); break;
         case 3:
            slide4(); break;
         default:
            slide1();
            slide = 0;
      }
      slide++;
   }, 500); // esse intervalo deve ser o mesmo do transition do CSS
}

function slide1() {
   document.getElementById("banner").src="https://www.cleverfiles.com/howto/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/mini.jpg";
   setTimeout(transicao, intervalo);
}

function slide2() {
   document.getElementById("banner").src="https://image.freepik.com/fotos-gratis/hrc-tigre-siberiano-2-jpg_21253111.jpg";
   setTimeout(transicao,  intervalo);
}

function slide3() {
   document.getElementById("banner").src="https://imagens.canaltech.com.br/123987.210185-JPG.jpg";
   setTimeout(transicao, intervalo);
}               

function slide4() {
   document.getElementById("banner").src="https://media.alienwarearena.com/media/1327-a.jpg";
   setTimeout(transicao, intervalo);
}  
slide1();
```

```css
#banner{
   width: 300px;
   transition: opacity 500ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="slide">
   <a href=""><img id="banner"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Sam, bom dia!

Muito obrigado, fiz da forma que você me mostrou.

Estou começando agora a desenvolver em JavaScript, preciso melhorar.